# macOS Mojave install disk locked

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, repair

I made a mistake when trying to reset my MacBook.

When I thought I was erasing the iCloud Disk, I instead erased my macOS Base System. I have troubleshooted it multiple times, including restarting the computer, coming down to <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and the Power Button to get to the reset stage and the Internet Recovery.

When I go to Install masOS Mojave, I went through the steps until I hit a road block. That road block being the macOS Base System disk is locked. I cannot click on it or go any further than the screen where you select the disk that you want to install macOS on. It is greed out and locked.

I read up on going quitting Install macOS Mojave and going into Disk Utility to erase the Apple SSD Media, but I cannot go any further as it does not allow me to Erase, Restore, or Mount this Internal Drive. These are also locked and past my capability of reaching.

Can I troubleshoot this at home without visiting an Apple store?